# Models with has_many through to each other -- how to find Model where it has a specific other Model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Tables:

Sales, Types, SaleTypes.

Sales has_many SaleTypes, has_many Types through SalesTypes.
Types has_many SaleTypes, has_many Sales through SalesTypes.

I want to find all Sales where Types.id == 1 OR is in [1, 2, 3].

So far the best solution is to do:

```
Sale.joins(:sale_types).where('sale_types.type_id = ?', '1')
```

However, this seems unwieldy and it does not accept arrays/multiple matches. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing join is the best way i can think of. Do this if you want to select sales based on multiple types

```
Sale.joins(:sale_types).where('sale_types.type_id in (?)', types)
```

Comment: Yeah, I think that's the only reasonable way. I feel like this is such a fundamental thing that there should be an easier way built in :/